# Why didn't I recieve the "Good Answer" badge?

Tags: support, badges

I gave an answer and got a score of more than 40 but still have not got silver badge called "Good Answer".
Will it take time to get it? I have read somewhere that some jobs are run after certain interval but I have still not received the badge.

Here is the screenshot where you can see that I got 65 points.
[image]

Comment: You have 5 upvotes on that answer. You need 25 to get the badge.

Comment: Didn´t Good Answer badge be awarded by 25 upvotes (not 25 scores)?

Comment: Score != Reputation, those two are confused many times.

Comment: @Spontifixus In question title, receive -> recieve, Answer -> Anwer?

Comment: @Pang: I love that. I submit a suggestion to improve the post, and introduce typos in the title myself. :/ Well spotted.

Comment: How about... "net votes" instead of "score". =D

Comment: @J.Steen i agree with you. Score seems to be confusing. Votes seems to be correct word.

Comment: @J.Steen no, net votes is too.. complex. Score is fine, when in doubt check the [glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/152859). :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ah yes, another place to check for reference information when English fails to be clear. ;) In all honesty, I find "net votes" vs "reputation" to be *far* more clear than "score" vs "reputation". But maybe that's just me and OP. =)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Keywords that have a special meaning could, maybe, have a tooltip with the information from the glossary.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Also, even the glossary is rather inconsistent: "*A user's "reputation" is the total **score** achieved by a user*". And yes, I know there's a proper glossary entry for score further down. Still. Inconsistent use of the word score! *rage, rant, froth*

Comment: @J.Steen well, if you feel you can improve the glossary go ahead, I did it more than once. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I just might! =) Anyway. We have all these Resources(tm) that seem to be somewhat not-easy to find. Yes, I know about the FAQ-that-isn't-the-FAQ-in-the-menu-bar, and that it links to the glossary. However, if someone thinks they know what score means, why should they even *try* to find a glossary? Having a glossary isn't an excuse for having ambiguous terminology. =)

Comment: @J.Steen true but honestly, can't think of anything we can do except explain those things when required.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah, I know. If we put up signs everywhere pointing to information that'd be useful to people, the site would be nothing *but* signs. =/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The score is the total of upvotes and downvotes on the question. Also, Good Answer is awarded for a score of 25, not 40, which means you'd need a *minimum* of 25 upvotes on the answer in order to get the badge. Your screenshot shows you gained +65 *reputation* from the answer. That is not the same thing as your answer's score.

That specific answer currently has a score of 5.

[image: Post Score]

Comment: I was confused with score and reputation. Now i understood. Thanks