# Understanding Tag badges

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

I very recently earned the below badge. But I am sorry, I do not understand it. 
[image]

It says

> Earned at least 100 total score for at least 20 answers in the java tag.

But I have answered 140 questions under Java tag and pretty sure would have earned more than 100 points. Then why did I receive it so late. Currently I have 3.3K points on SO.

Secondly if so, I have answered about 41 questions under Scala tag, then why didn't I receive this badge for Scala?

Comment: How many upvotes total did you get with answers in the Scala tag?

Comment: @TheProgramm3r Total number of upvotes? we it should be more than 40 I guess. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A894565+%5BScala%5D+is%3Aanswer

Comment: you need over 100 upvotes for each tag, total, AS WELL AS over 20 answers in that same tag, to get the badge

Comment: "Score" is net up-votes, not reputation. [We've asked for this to be clarified, but no action yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188260/clarify-what-score-means-in-badge-descriptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the answer if you mouseover to those numbers near the tags (127 near java and 51 near scala).

**Java:** 140 answer with total score of 127
[image: Java]

**Scala:** 38 answer with total score of 51
[image: Scala]

You just earned 51 Score for scala (Score = No. of Upvote - No. of Downvote), so you need 49 more to achieve that Scala Badge.

Answer (score 3):

Lets break it downs:

> - score = number of upvotes - number of downvotes
> - in the java tag = questions that have been tagged with the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag (or synonym)

So - you need to have at least 20 answers to questions with that tag and to have gotten a score of 100 on them.

> Secondly if so, I have answered about 41 questions under Scala tag, then why didn't I receive this badge for Scala?

What's your score on [scala](/questions/tagged/scala)? It is less than 100. It is currently 51.

You can see this information on [your profile tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894565/jatin?tab=tags) - hover over the tag to see the different scores in a tooltip.

Comment: just what i was trying to explain to him :D

Comment: Thanks. I confused score with points. Got it :)