# Badges not awarded even after eligibility

Tags: support, badges

As per my information I am eligible for badges *Enlightened* (first to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more) and *Guru* (accepted answer and score of 40 or more), also a few badges from answer section on Stack Overflow, but I have not been awarded by those badges.

May I know why I haven't received these badges?

Comment: I don't see 10 votes in your profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/1434688/cris

Comment: Related; [clarify-what-score-means-in-badge-descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188260/clarify-what-score-means-in-badge-descriptions). This is going to keep happening as long as we continue to use ambiguous terms

Comment: @RichardTingle: this is going to continue to happen as long as people don't read what is already there. The term `score` **is** explained in places, people just assume it means reputation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ha, the sun will have burnt out long before that happens. We need to design a system for humans, not for an idealised version of humans. The irritating thing is that there *is* a non ambiguous term: "net votes"

Comment: @RichardTingle: And yet people will not understand what "net votes" means either. People will be people, I am not idealising anyone, quite the opposite.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Perhaps, but culturally score is almost always 10x the number of "scoring events". I have no idea why, it seems stupid (think a games machine, every 'hit' will usually increase the score by 10). As such the word score is culturally polluted and the idea that it is reputation (which is 10x 'hits') is easy to make. On the other hand net votes has only one meaning

Comment: I had an idea which I explained in this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204658/list-of-badges-add-hyperlink-to-score-explanation-page. Maybe that could help a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your answers and sorting them by votes, the highest number of votes ever received on a single answer of yours is only *5*, whereas the criteria for the 2 badges in discussion are

- Enlightened - First to answer and accepted with a score of 10
- Guru - Accepted answer and score of 40 or more

Since none of answers satisfy either of these conditions, none was awarded to you.

Comment: ohh the score is for votes not for reputation,my bad :)

Comment: Yes, the score means the *no. of upvotes* on any of your answers.

Comment: thanks,that explains all

Comment: @R.J - No. Score is no. of upvotes - no. of downvotes

Comment: Yes, sorry, that what I meant. Total no. of votes = Score = (no. of upvotes - no. of downvotes). Thanks for clarifying it.