# List of badges - add hyperlink to score explanation page

Tags: feature-request, badges, score

Every now and then, people misunderstand the term *score* when it comes to badges (e.g. just recently [Badges not awarded even after eligibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204652/badges-not-awarded-even-after-eligibility)). This happens to new users who either don't bother to check what score means or can't find the explanation or simply assume that score is the same as reputation.

Can the word score in the badges description be turned into a hyperlink leading to the score explanation/help page. BTW, which is the best page explaining score? I wanted to add a link to the help/explanation page in here but couldn't find a good one.

This will not break the simple layout of the badges page and may improve usability of SO for new users. The same could be done for other terms on the badges page if needed.

**UPDATE**

**This request is not about changing the existing word "score"**. It's to add a hyperlink so please don't treat is a duplicate of questions asking to change the wording.

Comment: Why is there a question *BTW, which is the best page explaining score?* inside this *feature-request*?

Comment: Somewhat similar post: [Clarify what “score” means in badge descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188260/clarify-what-score-means-in-badge-descriptions).

Comment: I wanted to add a link to the help/explanation page for *score* but couldn't find one.

Comment: @AzizShaikh It's similar but I don't propose to change the existing wording. I propose to add a hyperlink.

Comment: @Szymon I understand, which is why the "somewhat similar" text :)

Comment: Might this not lead to also adding links to explain what bounties, favoriting, accepting, community wiki, flagging, rollbacks, editing, etc. are (i.e. linking to most of what's said in the help centre, which is probably too much)?

Comment: @Dukeling Maybe... But score seems to cause most grieve. Maybe also because it's not easy to find an explanation.

Comment: @Dukeling would that not be a good thing?

Comment: Or we could have a glossary kind of thing, where all these terms will be explained in short, with detailed explanations in individual pages.

Comment: @RichardTingle Well, two approaches comes to mind - (1) dedicate an massive section at the top or the bottom of the page to this (with either links or explanations), which is too much screen space to dedicate to what's already said elsewhere, or (2) [tag:Fill] [tag:the] [tag:entire] page [tag:with] [tag:links], which doesn't [tag:look] [tag:particularly] [tag:good].

Comment: The only issue with linking is it is more to maintain when something changes.  I think the other proposal that @AzizShaikh found accomplishes the same thing with less to maintain.

Comment: @Szymon After reading through this and looking at the answers on the other question, I think this is a dup of the "similar" post reference earlier.  One of the answers there explicitly suggesting a link "score" tag wiki page.  I put a bounty on that question to see if something can be done