# In SO I have questions with score of 25 or more but no good question badge, why not?

Tags: support, badges

Silver badge for good question is defined as "Question score of 25 or more" and I think bronze for nice question is 10 points or more.

I have asked quite a few questions by now many over 10 points and I just had once that got 25 points (i.e. 5 upvotes) but I just noticed that I did not receive any badges for either nice or good questions (and probably same for answers though I have not looked into that yet). Not that I am a "badge collector", but its nice to get the bonus if you have "achieved" it.

Why do I not get these badges? what am I missing here? - I had a look on Meta-SO but didn't see anything obvious like my question.

Here is an example of one question that has 5 votes: [5-vote-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159379/is-it-correct-to-cast-an-integer-to-enumerated-type).
Ok in this instance it was marked as "duplicate" (even though I searched before asking it, you don't always find what you are looking for), but it still matches the 25-point criteria...

Comment: This is a confusion with score vs rep, a 5 vote question has a score of 5

Comment: Score != reputation. Score = upvotes-downvotes.

Comment: dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167400/why-didnt-i-recieve-the-good-answer-badge

Comment: Related: [Clarify what “score” means in badge descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188260/clarify-what-score-means-in-badge-descriptions)

Comment: Also see [the glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

Comment: Thanks all, this is now clear to me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an (understandable) confusion between score and rep from a question.

The score of a question is its `upvotes - downvotes`. It is not the rep generated from it.

Therefore your linked example has a score of 5, even though it may have gained you 25 reputation (or more depending on if it also has downvotes)

Comment: Got it, thanks! - yes, I was confused with this :)